# Get particular result in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this result in JSON, but I want to get the description only to display.

`"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "result": {"success": {"status": 200, "message": "200 OK", "code": 200, "description": "Customer record was successfully created."}, "data": {"id": 56229}}}"`

Ive tried this but no success

```
$res = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($res);
$result = json_decode($res);
echo $result['success']['description'];
```

Comment: Use `$result = json_decode($res, true);` to parse the JSON as associative array and extract the correct item with `echo $result['result']['success']['description'];`.

Comment: `'success'` isn't at the root of the JSON, but contained in another property : `result`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `json_decode()` decodes JSON strings into PHP objects by default, not associative arrays. You can access object properties using the arrow `->` operator, not array notation.

```
$res = curl_exec($curl);

if ($res === false) {
    echo "cURL error: " . curl_error($curl);
} else {
    $result = json_decode($res, true);

    if ($result === null) {
        echo "Failed to decode JSON: " . json_last_error_msg();
    } else {
        if (isset($result['result']['success']['description'])) {
            echo $result['result']['success']['description'];
        } else {
            echo "Description not found in the JSON data.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but heres the result

Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: I am sorry but the error mostly appears if the JSON is not valid, I have updated the post to help you find the problem (is it with JSON or cURL request) and check if the JSON is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, this is from JSON response, after successfully added record

Comment: So you have fixed it! great to hear!